# How to run Kubernetes from a local PC?

Tags: kubernetes

I have downloaded the kubernetes from GitHub and now I want to run it from the downloaded file not from GitHub. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow:

- "[Assign Memory Resources to Containers and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/)"
- "[Assign CPU Resources to Containers and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/)"

That is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cpu-demo
  namespace: cpu-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: demo-ctr
    image: vish/stress
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: "200Mi"
      requests:
        cpu: "0.5"
        memory: "100Mi"
    args:
    - -cpus
    - "2"
```

At the pod level: "[Configure a Pod Quota for a Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-pod-namespace/)".